# Python, How do I place a commas after each interger in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer

Say I have the the following...

```
 aaa = 5
```

can i turn that into

```
 newaaa = 1,2,3,4,5
```

...? with commas included.

thanks in advance

Comment: so a `tuple` as the result? Have you given this any attempts? If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: Sure, a for loop with string concatenation would work.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard A string would be the result.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek doesn't seem like it from the question, that's why I asked.

Comment: As I stated below I haven't used tuples before So I attempted doing it with loops which obviously didn't work but I'm all as good now. Thanks for the help lads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question, if I understand it correctly:

```
newaaa = tuple(range(1, aaa+1))
```

EDIT: according to the comment, the question was wrong, so I did not understand correctly. You need a string as a result. So second attempt:

```
newaaa = ",".join(str(i) for i in range(1, aaa+1))
```

Please make the effort to write syntactically and semantically correct code in your question...

Comment: you could drop the `tuple` call if you like unpacking with `newaaa = *range(1, aaa+1),`.

Comment: Sure, that is available since Python 3.5

Comment: Legend, I was in a rush with the question so thank you for giving such a good answer. I definitely need to look further into tuples as I haven't touched on them as of yet.